# Android: google maps, my gps location is not shown, if gps is turning on after launching the app

Tags: android, gps, position

In my app I use a map view with the possibility to locate my gps position.

All work finally if I turn on gps and wait for the gps fix, BEFORE launching the app.
The problem appears if I turn on gps AFTER launching the app, because in the map the position doesn't appear.

this is my code on my MapActivity:

```
private MapView mapView;
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
private MapController mapController;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_sensor);

    // Configure the Map
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapController = mapView.getController();


    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(47.6945683 *1E6 ,11.5765886 *1E6);
    mapController.animateTo(point);

    mapController.setZoom(9); // Zoom 1 is world view

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            50, new GeoUpdateHandler());
    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);


    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to trigger `locationListener` once again after you turn on GPS in order to get location updates.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
        50, new GeoUpdateHandler());
```

Hope its helpful.

Edit : In my case, triggering location update code is in onResume method. So, if GPS is not turned on and user turned it on, while coming to Activity back, it will get triggered once again automatically.

Comment: more exactly what should I do to trigger locationListener?

Comment: again need to request for location updates as shown in answer(locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...))

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the `requestLocationUpdates()` function to be set up, which you have.

GPS takes up to 30 seconds to give a first fix.

I personally let my `Activity` implements `LocationListener` and it works well (API 7+).

Try to add a button that will `animateTo()` you current position to check that GPS is working fine in your application even when it has been enabled afterward.

Also try to move your location-related code from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`.